# How to send m4v using pyrogram?

Tags: python, video, telegram, pyrogram, m4v

How to send m4v through pyrogram not like a file, but like a video, that you can watch in the app?

This is what i tried:

```
app.send_video(receiver_id, "video", supports_streaming=True)
```

Comment: What is error ?

Comment: @jakbin there isn't any error, but it's sending like a file, so to watch a video you need to download it and open through a player. i want it to be playable inside the Telegram(it works if i'm sending it  manually)

Comment: Telegram client support only mp4 video file, other will sent as document.